# Set fix width of each Column DIV Control

Tags: html, css

I have written tabular structure using DIV controls. It shows data correct only when column values have same length of characters. If column values have different number of characters then column gets enlarge itself to accommodate all characters in a column. How to set FIX width of each column DIV?

I have following HTML DIV structure:

```
<body>
  <div class="ParentContainer">
    <div id="row1" class="row">
        <div>
            <label id="row1_to" class="divLabel">contact1@test.com
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label id="row1_from" class="fromLabel">test1@something.com
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label id="row1_subject" class="subLabel">Need to create new organization1
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row2" class="row">
        <div>
            <label id="row2_to" class="divLabel">contact2@test.com
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label id="row2_from" class="fromLabel">test2@something.com
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label id="row2_subject" class="subLabel">Need to create new organization2
            </label>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Following is the CSS:

```
.ParentContainer
{
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 960px;
table-layout:fixed;
}
.row
{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-bottom-style: solid !important;
border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
border-color: #CFD4DA;
font-size: 12px;
}
.row > div
{
display: inline-block;
}
.row:hover
{
background-color: #CEE3F6 !important;
}
.rowSelected
{
    background-color: #CEE3F6;
}
.fromLabel
{
    position: relative;
    left: 64px;
}
.subLabel
{
    position: relative;
    left: 120px;
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Fix height or width?>

Comment: Width. I have added this in my post now.

Comment: Something like this: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/NKK3B/)?

Comment: If it's truly tabular then I would just use tables. What I don't see though in your example is any sort of heading, which makes me thing it's not tabular (or accessible really). You could use display:table-row and table-cell to get what you need, as long as your target audience is on the latest browsers the support should be there.

Comment: Yup i agree with nhavar @NidaSulheri u should go for the tabular format which will not destroy your design in all resolutions

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to style those `div` as `table`:

*Relevant CSS*:

```
.ParentContainer {
    display: table;
    ...
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
    ...
}
.row > div {
    display: table-cell;
    ...
}
```

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/824hw/1/***

Answer (score 0):

Make your div display as a table cell and assign width for the table cell. Remove position relative property for your labels.

Update your css like below.

```
.ParentContainer
{
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 960px;
table-layout:fixed;
}
.row
{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-bottom-style: solid !important;
border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
border-color: #CFD4DA;
font-size: 12px;
display:table-row;
}
.row > div
{
display: table-cell;
width:33%;
}
.row:hover
{
background-color: #CEE3F6 !important;
}
.rowSelected
{
background-color: #CEE3F6;
}
.fromLabel, .subLabel, .divLabel
{
  text-align:left;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MRXc3/)